# Advice on transaction log based reporting server

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping, reporting

I am in need of advice on setting up a remote read-only MSSQL 2008 reporting server using transaction logs.

From what I gather, true TLS setup requires both database servers to be aware of each other however in my case the server where the logs will be applied is in no way connected to the primary server.

I am using the following steps to replicate data to the reporting server approximately every 15 minutes.

1. Download incremental or full backup file posted to a SFTP server
2. Put database into single user mode
3. Apply backup (with replace, standby)
4. Put database into multi user mode

The problem I am having is the database is unavailable to applications during the period when the database is in single user mode. Is there a better solution for what I am attempting to accomplish where the database wouldn't need to refuse connections, or could queue connections until the backup has been applied?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to look into replication if you need to keep the database online at all times

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Replication between the server that supports the application is not an option at this time. Would you suggest replicating locally between the read only standby server and another local server or instance?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a better solution for what I am attempting to accomplish where the database wouldn't need to refuse connections, or could queue connections until the backup has been applied?

You need to write some manual code and change backups .Please see below article which we are also applying from Aaron bertrand

http://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/sql-performance/readable-secondaries-on-a-budget

Comment: Thank you for the response - We will evaluate this solution to see if it is feasible for us.